# I keep getting a time out error for all servers in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I log in to a server, log out later, and log in again, Minecraft keeps giving me a time out error for all servers.

I have tried restarting my computer, and I also tried restarting Minecraft. But it did not work.

The only solution I found that works is turning my Internet connection off, then turning my Internet connection back on, but I cannot do that all the time. Please give me another solution.

Comment: I can tell you that you probably need to get a better internet connection or go closer to your router

Comment: Then why does the game work fine and then all of a sudden it can't connect anymore? @angussidney

Comment: Also, the internet works fine for websites and youtube videos.

Comment: No idea. I'm not an expert, but my very basic troubleshooting instinct tells me that. Also browsing the internet or watching youtube is quite different to playing a game online.

Comment: Another thing, my ping is 504ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How far away is the server? If it's thousands of miles then that could explain a high ping and thus a timeout.

Other options are, like said in the comments, a router or internet issue. What kind of router do you have? Older routers tend to play up every now and then, especially when used intensively. The only way to resolve that is - like you said - reboot it. The solution to that would be to get a new router, you have good ones for 30-ish bucks these days. If that's not it it might simply be your internet. But honestly to be sure we'd need a lot more info, like what router you have, where you and the server are, internet speed etc...

Comment: That would be true if it was for servers where he had a bad latency with. If it's with all servers it may be something else

Comment: True, but that doesn't rule out the router or internet being the culprit.